# SQL multiple Query

Tags: mysql

i have this condition :

```
select AVG(t_vote.rating) as AVG_1 from t_vote  
INNER JOIN t_question.c_question = t_vote.c_question 
where t_question.aspect_code = 'A';

select AVG(t_vote.rating) as AVG_2 from t_vote  
INNER JOIN t_question.c_question = t_vote.c_question 
where t_question.aspect_code = 'B';

select AVG(t_vote.rating) as AVG_3 from t_vote  
INNER JOIN t_question.c_question = t_vote.c_question 
where t_question.aspect_code = 'C';
```

is it possible to get these 3 different values with 3 different 'where' clauses in 1 query ?

this is my table structure, correct me if i'm wrong 
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WVAZ.jpg)

i make this table as an example but my table actually look like this
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOoCB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN t_question.aspect_code = 'A' THEN AVG(t_vote.rating) END AS AVG_1,
  CASE WHEN t_question.aspect_code = 'B' THEN AVG(t_vote.rating) END AS AVG_2, 
  CASE WHEN t_question.aspect_code = 'C' THEN AVG(t_vote.rating) END AS AVG_3 
FROM t_vote 
JOIN t_question 
  ON t_question.c_question = t_vote.c_question AND 
     t_question.aspect_code IN ('A', 'B', 'C');
```

Comment: a `GROUP BY` with filtering on `aspect_code` would give you more concise code

Comment: i have tried it sir ... but i have NULL value on AVG_2 and AVG_3.. btw i do it in multiple join tables , is it have an impact to the queries ?

Comment: @ChristopelSianturi if you are joining, query will have to be formulated differently. Add more details to the question and let me know here.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya edited sir .. that is the join condition that i have beside the other join that is not relate to the result of the query

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya same result sir .. i've tried it so many times .. i tried to modify it too

Comment: @ChristopelSianturi post sample data in both your tables. Something definitely wrong with the data and it is hard to figure out without looking at the data now

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya u can check my table example now sir .. correct me if im wrong :)